# Syscalls in strace

Tags: process, pipe, system-calls, strace

I called `strace` on some program `A` which forks two child programs: `B` and `C`.

In `strace`, I have the following `syscalls`:

```
 pipe[([3,4]) = 0
 pipe([5,6]) = 0
 fork(wc) = 7135
 fork (gnetcat) = 7136
 close(3) = 0
 close(5) = 0
 close(4) = 0
 close(6) = 0
 wait4(-1, NULL, 0, NULL) = 7136
 wait4(-1, NUKLL, 0, NULL) = 7135
```

I am trying to rewrite the program `A` in C. In that case, I really never really have to know what those file descriptors `3`,`4`,`5` and `6` stand for, do I? Is there a way to find out what they are? I know `3` is for `stderr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0 ist STDIN, 1 is STDOUT and 2 is STDERR. All higher numbers are up to the application. In this case I suspect they are used to capture stdout/stderr of the freshly forked programs. This would mean that "wc" probably runs with its stdout connected to fd 3 and stderr to fd 4, so the main application can could the output of wc.

Comment: Why are file descriptors empty files then? How would they work in piping the data? To be able to implement it in C, it really wouldn't matter what `4` and all higher file descriptors mean, does it? I can just pass them into the pipes, right?

Comment: the file descriptors are the representation of the (opened) pipe. You need an fd to be able to identify where you are writing to. - As your strace contains no read() or write() it appears that nothing is sent over these pipes which is a bit strange. -- But the "fork(program)" suggest you edited it :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should try running strace again with the -f flag so that it follows forks. At the moment you can only see what your top-level process does, you can't see what your child processes do.

The top-level process creates two pipes. Pipes are used by programs to communicate with each other. The first pipe has the read end on fd 3 and the write end on fd 4. The second pipe has the read end on fd 5 and the write end on fd 6.

Since the top-level program closes all four fds after calling the two child programs, it looks like they are just used internally by the child programs (who both get copies of the fds). This is unusually becuase normally I would expect to see the parent process keep one en open in orfer to communicate with the child. It looks like your trace is missing some important information about what happened to the fds after each fork.

This is what I would expect to see if a progcess was opening pipes inorder to capture stdout from a child, for example:

```
parent_pid: pipe[3,4]
parent_pid: clone() = child_pid
parent_pid: close(4)
child_pid:  dup(4,1)
child_pid:  close(4)
child_pid:  close(3)
child_pid:  execve(some program)
child_pid:  write(1)
parent_pid: read(3)
parent_pid: wait(child_pid)
child_pid:  exit()
```